# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE undefined

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I know that there a lot of questions regarding this and I have actually gone through them all but I am unable to solve the problem.  I am trying to run a python webapp on (python 2.7) GAE by following a tutorial for GAE based on python 2.5 (from: Head First Python chap. 10). This requires the creation of a form using djangoforms. However, on runnning GAE server, I got the error: "ImportError: no module named django.core.exceptions".

After following the various discussions regarding this error on this forum, I came to know that I had to add the following two lines to my app.yaml file for python 2.7:

```
libraries   
- name: django  
  version: "1.4"
```

and had to include the 'threadsafe' attribute too. I even had to 'rename' my app name with an extension of '.app' instead of '.py' so that I am able to use the 'threadsafe' attribute.

However, I get the error 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined'. I tried to install django 'exclusively'. I even (desperately) created a new django project and moved the settings file into a subfolder titled 'django' in my webapp. However, I am still getting errors. Currently, my app.yaml file looks like this:

```
application: hfwwg  
version: 1  
runtime: python27  
api_version: 1  
threadsafe: true  

env_variables:  
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'django/settings.py'

handlers:  
- url: /.*  
  script: hfwwg.app  
- url: /static  
  static_dir: static  

libraries:  
- name: django  
  version: "1.4"
```

Please suggest how to remove the 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' error or any other place where there is error. Any help would be appreciated.

And here is the portion of the code where I have used django:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp  
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app  
from google.appengine.ext import db  
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template  
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms  

...  

class MyForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):  

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'django/settings.py'
```

this should be

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'django.settings'
```

[LINK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, there is this error again:

File "/home/head/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py", line 98, in <module>  

    import django.core.exceptions  

ImportError: No module named core.exceptions

INFO     2015-01-17 08:15:36,932 module.py:718] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Python_user your django isnot available. if you are in virtualenv, you need to activate it.

Comment: So how can I make it avaliable to GAE? (Sorry, but I am new to Django and dont know a lot of things about it)... Moreover, I am using Ubuntu as my OS..

Comment: I dont know GAE either much. but take a look at this: http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-on-appengine-using-google-cloud you need ``export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$GAE:$GAE/lib/django_1_4"
export PATH=${PATH}:$GAE/lib/django_1_4/django/bin/``

Comment: Moving the settings.py to the top folder of web app worked! 

And had to change the name to 

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'settings'

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Python_user perfect! :)